# I can't install Composer to use CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, composer-php

I want to learn CakePHP and install it using Composer, but I'm getting the following error on Composer Setup:

```
The PHP exe file you specified did not run correctly:
C:\xampp\php\php.exe

The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini

Program Output:
Warning: PHP Startup: PDO: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20131226
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
```

Can Someone help me to figure out this problem?

PHP Version: 5.6

Comment: This question is more fit for Super User than Stack Overflow, as it's not about programming per se. (it's about fiddling with software to be able to program, in some sense)

Comment: **https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3324**

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `php` in your environment variables, and then use it like `php composer.phar update` in your project directory.

P.S. You can find some details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

**It's working now**

I commented php_pdo.dll in php.ini and installed CakePHP using command prompt inside htdocs folder and I ran this command: composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app cakephp